MongoDB - Batch Processing Question/Debugging
I'm working on processing chess games and saving data to a database.  My partner developed this batch processing and concurrent threads to run a few in parallel.  We want to write each game accuracy, opening_accuracy, middlegame_accuracy, endgame_accuracy, rating, and moves to the MongoDB but I think right now we are writing the average/mean over and over again. I'm not super familiar with MongoDB or concurrent.futures so I'm hoping someone could provide a bit of guidance:
def process_games(self, records: list[dict]):
    game_list = pd.DataFrame(columns=PlayerAnalysis.game_columns)
    start_time = time.time()
    try:
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
            # This dict is used to hold the futures objects and their labels (in
            # this case indexes).
            numbered_futures = {}

            # This dict is used to hold the partial data frames created by the
            # futures while their results are being corrected.
            game_detail_dframe_dict = {}

            index = 1
            timer = 999

            # This loop generates the futures. They start automatically.
            for record in records:
                body: dict = json.loads(record.get("body", None))
                time_control = body.get("time_control", None)
                game_str: str = body.get("game", None)
                depth: int = body.get("depth", None)
                job_id: str = body.get("job_id", None)
                username: str = body.get("username", None)

                # ADD ERROR HANDLING IF ANY MISSING....
                processed_game = chess.pgn.read_game(io.StringIO(game_str))

                if processed_game is None:
                    raise InvalidGame

                # For game_detail() to run properly in its own thread it needs its
                # own Limit and Engine objects. This factory function builds a
                # PlayerAnalysis object with private copies of both.
                player_analysis_obj = PlayerAnalysis.from_depth_and_timer(
                    depth, timer
                )

                # verbose_game_detail() is just a game_detail() call plus it
                # prints when it's starting and ending.
                future_obj = executor.submit(
                    player_analysis_obj.verbose_game_detail,
                    index,
                    processed_game,
                    username,
                    job_id,
                )
                numbered_futures[future_obj] = index
                index += 1

            # This loop collects the results of the futures in the order they
            # complete.
            for game_detail_future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(numbered_futures):
                index = numbered_futures[game_detail_future]
                try:
                    result: FutureResponse = game_detail_future.result()

                    # Process game_detail_future result and store in game_detail_dframe_dict
                    game_detail_dframe_dict[index] = result.game_details

                    game_list = pd.concat(
                        [game_list, game_detail_dframe_dict[index]], axis=0
                    ).fillna(0)

                    jobs_collections.insert_one(
                        {
                            "job_id": result.job_id,
                            "status": "COMPLETE",
                            "overall_accuracy": game_list["ACC"].mean(),
                            "opening_accuracy": game_list["Opening_ACC"].mean(),
                            "middlegame_accuracy": game_list["Middlegame_ACC"].mean(),
                            "endgame_accuracy": game_list["Endgame_ACC"].mean(),
                            "stephan_rating": game_list["Rating"].mean(),
                            "number_of_moves": game_list["Moves"].mean(),
                        },
                    )

                    self.logger.info(
                        f"Thread #{index} Completed Job ID: [{result.job_id}]"
                    )
                except Exception as exc:
                    self.logger.error(
                        f"thread job for game #{index} generated an exception: {exc}"
                    )
                end_time = time.time()
                time_elapsed = end_time - start_time
                self.logger.info("completed in %.1f seconds" % time_elapsed)

            return game_list

    except Exception as e:
        self.logger.error(traceback.print_exc())
        self.logger.error(e)


When I look at the database, I would expect the number of moves and the rating to be integer values. But when I looked, some are integers and some are floats (31.666 moves). When I saw this, I knew the insert_one...mean() is the problem. But I'm not exactly sure how to index each game to send it to the mongoDB.

Before you insert data in mongo DB you can convert moves into integer in your application code, or when you retrive data also use $toInt like this  https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/ Example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/rt4TOW4LVXW
